# Retrieving dates from foreign table based on form values

Tags: ms-access

I have a form where I can allocate course runs for the next work year. So I have 3 basic courses (Course1, Course2, Course3). Each of these courses have several course runs every year; data about the course is stored in a separate table called CourseRuns (with each course having its own table).

So what I would like to do is to retrieve dates from my CourseRuns table. So if my form is populated as such:

```
Course1: Run 2
Course2: Run 1
Course3: -
```

I want to see the course dates for the course runs that were selected in the form.

If possible, I'd also like to know if it is possible to use the course dates to validate the record (I do not want clashing allocated course dates)

Answer (score 0):

In the on-current event you can call a routine that refreshes read-only labels/textboxes that display the information you refer to. In the after-update events for the course fields you would call this routine again. The routine itself would take the primary key from the course1 / course2 / course3 textbox/comboboxes (whatever they are) and do a dlookup() on the CourseRuns table with appropriate filters. Take resulting values from the DLookup() and place them in your read-only FYI fields. If you find yourself doing many DLookups() and the code starts bogging down, I believe you'll find a more efficient solution with a recordset approach, but in practice I doubt that will prove necessary.